# ERROR] : Failed to package application?(Appcelerator Studio)

Tags: android, appcelerator

I have just install Appcelerator Studio and do All settings.

Now I have create my first Application and run on Android.

Then getting below error message.

Please help me how I can sort-out this problem

```
{
ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  invalid resource directory name: /var/folders/6w/68fb7_vd6yjd2bgxd0lfd0sw0000gn/T/11553-1191-1tyydgj/res/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi
[ERROR] :  invalid resource directory name: /var/folders/6w/68fb7_vd6yjd2bgxd0lfd0sw0000gn/T/11553-1191-1tyydgj/res/drawable-ldrtl-mdpi
[ERROR] :  invalid resource directory name: /var/folders/6w/68fb7_vd6yjd2bgxd0lfd0sw0000gn/T/11553-1191-1tyydgj/res/drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi
[ERROR] :  invalid resource directory name: /var/folders/6w/68fb7_vd6yjd2bgxd0lfd0sw0000gn/T/11553-1191-1tyydgj/res/drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi
[ERROR] :  invalid resource directory name: /var/folders/6w/68fb7_vd6yjd2bgxd0lfd0sw0000gn/T/11553-1191-1tyydgj/res/drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi
[ERROR] :  invalid resource directory name: /var/folders/6w/68fb7_vd6yjd2bgxd0lfd0sw0000gn/T/11553-1191-1tyydgj/res/drawable-xxhdpi
[ERROR] :  invalid resource directory name: /var/folders/6w/68fb7_vd6yjd2bgxd0lfd0sw0000gn/T/11553-1191-1tyydgj/res/drawable-xxxhdpi
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/mritunjaysingh/.appcelerator/install/4.0.1/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:84:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It seems there is an issue with the resource folder structure. The folder names are also weird. Can you validate whether the folders mentioned in the logs are actually valid or not.

Comment: I have just create new application. and nothing add any thing. Just install in device then got this message.

Comment: Can you share the environment and the SDK versions which you are using. Along with the Android SDK information.

Comment: Mac Yasomite, Appcelerator Studio 4.0.1, Android_OSx_SDK.

Comment: Check in the Android SDK folder and try to use Android build tools 20 and see if that resolves the issues.

Comment: Can you look into this link and see whether it resolves your issue or not:
https://community.appcelerator.com/topic/653/error-while-building-for-android-emulator-or-device/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had the same issue. My problem was with targeted sdk version.  Earlier it was 19. When I changed to 21, which was the latest build tool version in my Android sdk folders.  This issue solved.  Some other post also found related to build tool version.